# Calling the system through C++ inconsistently fails

Tags: python, c++, bash, ubuntu, system

I'm trying to launch a Python script by using the system call through C++, on Ubuntu. The problem is that this command sometimes works, but more often than not, it fails and throws one of two errors:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
sh: 1: xK-��: not found
```

The code I'm using:

```
std::string pythonPath = "/home/myuser/Programs/miniconda3/envs/Py37/bin/python3.7";    
std::string viewerScript = "/home/myuser/Projects/Pycharm/MyProject/script.py";
std::string command = pythonPath + " " + viewerScript;
std::thread* t = new std::thread(system, command.c_str());
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data buffer returned by `c_str` is only guaranteed to be valid until the next time you access the string in various ways, in particular destroying it. So if `command` is about to go out of scope, it's a race between this thread destroying the buffer, and the new thread using the buffer in `system`.

Rather than making a thread with `system` as an entry point, use a lambda which takes the string by value, keeping it alive until `system` is done with it.

```
std::thread* t = new std::thread([command]() { system(command.c_str()); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sneftel, I was actually just about to post the solution I've found to it, but I didn't have a good explanation to why it worked. I've moved the string into a function together with the system command and then launched that function in a thread. It's basically identical to your solution!

Comment: The `new std::thread` is also a bit suspect. `std::thread` is already a handle class; `std::thread t{ [command]...` would work equally well.